# trouble embeding php in EOD tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to assign the value from a drop down list to a variable as follows:

```
<?php



$submittedValue = "";
$value0 = " ";
$value1 = "mr";
$value2 = "ms";
$value3 = "mrs";
if (isset($_POST["salute"])) {
    $submittedValue = $_POST["salute"];
}


$html =null;



//form with data
$html .= "

        <form action='' name='salute' method='post'>
        <select project='salute' id='salute' name='Salute'>
         <option value = '<?php echo $value0; ?>'<?php echo ($value0 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''?>><?php echo $value0; ?></option>
         <option value = '<?php echo $value1; ?>'<?php echo ($value0 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''?>><?php echo $value1; ?></option>
         <option value = '<?php echo $value2; ?>'<?php echo ($value0 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''?>><?php echo $value2; ?></option>
         <option value = '<?php echo $value3; ?>'<?php echo ($value0 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''?>><?php echo $value3; ?></option>
        </select>
        </form>

        ";
?>
```

Which I want to access later as follows:

```
$test['main'] = <<<EOD


{$html}


EOD;
```

However, I am embedding it incorrectly, I know that the first part should not be written like that  in the $html variable. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is called a "[HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Quick note. You had `name='Salute'` with an uppercase `S` which should have been `name='salute'` - This would have caused an error in conjunction with `$_POST["salute"]`

```
<?php
$submittedValue = "";
$value0 = " ";
$value1 = "mr";
$value2 = "ms";
$value3 = "mrs";
if (isset($_POST["salute"])) {
    $submittedValue = $_POST["salute"];

}

$html =null;

//form with data
$html .= "

        <form action='' name='salute' method='post'>
        <select project='salute' id='salute' name='salute'>
         <option value = ' $value0 ' ($value0 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''>$value0</option>
         <option value = ' $value1 ' ($value1 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''>$value1</option>
         <option value = ' $value2 ' ($value2 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''>$value2</option>
         <option value = ' $value3 ' ($value3 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''>$value3</option>
        </select>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>

        </form>

        ";

echo $test['main'] = <<<EOD

{$html}

$submittedValue

EOD;
```

---

Give this a try. It did echo the dropdown menu, however I am not sure if it's the desired result to work in conjunction with your present ternary operators.

If it's not, I can delete this, or you can modify it.

```
<?php
$submittedValue = "";
$value0 = " ";
$value1 = "mr";
$value2 = "ms";
$value3 = "mrs";
if (isset($_POST["salute"])) {
    $submittedValue = $_POST["salute"];
}


$html =null;

//form with data
$html .= "

        <form action='' name='salute' method='post'>
        <select project='salute' id='salute' name='Salute'>
         <option value = '$value0'($value0 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''>$value0</option>
         <option value = '$value1'($value0 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''>$value1</option>
         <option value = '$value2'($value0 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''>$value2</option>
         <option value = '$value3'($value0 == $submittedValue)?' SELECTED':''>$value3</option>
        </select>
        </form>

        ";

echo $test['main'] = <<<EOD
<h1>{$test['title']}</h1>

{$html}

EOD;
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much, the drop down list works now, however I am not able to assign the value of the selected item to a variable which is my intention. I am still testing please do not remove it yet...

Comment: Ok and you're welcome. I noticed that `name='Salute'` has an upper-case `S` and it should be lowercase `name='salute'` - I posted an edit which did echo out the values from the choice in dropdown menu. @user1179105

Comment: Right on, glad to hear it and you're quite welcome. I'm glad it worked, cheers! @user1179105

Answer (score 0):

First
    `<option value = '<?php echo $value0; ?>'`
Should be `<option value='$value0'`

Now the problem I see is `<h1>{$test['title']}</h1>`

try `$title = $test['title']` before the EOD then

```
$test['main'] = <<< EOD
<h1>$title</h1>

{$html}

EOD;
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, the title tag in my page controller looks okay, even if I removed it the problem persists, I think it has to do with the $html '...'; variable, for example  <?php echo "hello"; ?> does not work and in my IDE it is colored as text in my not as php code.